# Jenkins Pipeline Script - evaluate stdout of batch/powershell

Tags: powershell, batch-file, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I want to evaluate a powershell/bat call in a jenkins pipeline script. 
The powershell script file is called with a bat script (defined inside the pipeline script).

I can get the return stdoutout of the ps / bat script into a variable and now I have problems evaluating it properly.

Here is the script:

```
pipeline {
    agent any

    stages {
         stage('Checkout') {
             steps {

                // Powershell Skript auschecken
                checkout([$class: 'SubversionSCM', additionalCredentials: [], excludedCommitMessages: '', excludedRegions: '', excludedRevprop: '', excludedUsers: 'someUser', filterChangelog: false, ignoreDirPropChanges: false, includedRegions: '', locations: [[cancelProcessOnExternalsFail: true, credentialsId: 'someid', depthOption: 'infinity', ignoreExternalsOption: true, local: 'localPath', remote: '${CopySkript}']], quietOperation: true, workspaceUpdater: [$class: 'CheckoutUpdater']])              
             }
         }



        stage('CopyPitchDBFrontend') {
            steps {
                script {


                    def myBat = new StringBuilder()
                    myBat.append("%SystemRoot%\\\\syswow64\\\\WindowsPowerShell\\\\v1.0\\\\powershell.exe -File %WORKSPACE%\\\\myScript.ps1 -dbTargetPath \\\\123.123.123.123\\myfile.file -dbSvnPath http://myserver.com/repo/trunk/myfile.file")


                    def result = bat(
                                    returnStdout    : true,
                                    script: "${myBat.toString()}"
                                    )


                    echo result.trim()

                    if (result.trim() == "0")
                    {
                        echo 'Myresult: Success'
                        currentBuild.result = 'SUCCESS'
                    }
                    else if (result.trim() == "-1"){
                        echo 'My result: Failure -1'
                        currentBuild.result = 'FAILURE'
                    }
                    else{
                        echo 'My result: Failure unknown'
                        currentBuild.result = 'FAILURE'

                    }
                }
            }           

        }
    }
}
```

Here is the console output of a successful script call.
By that I mean the script returns 0 (see second line).

```
some text
0
[Pipeline] echo
My result: Failure unknown
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // script
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withEnv
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
Finished: FAILURE
```

The execution jumps into the else branch of the if, which I do not understand.
`(result.trim() == "0")` , no?
I tried `(result.trim() == 0)` as well
but the result is the same.

Whats going on with the result value?

Maybe there is a better approach to do this?

Answer (score 4):

If you are trying to evaluate the exit code of a command, then the easiest path for this is to utilize the `returnStatus` argument of the `bat` method. This will return the status value of the command as an integer type. You can then adjust your code like the following:

```
Integer result = bat( // fine tune type specification
  returnStatus: true,
  script:       "${myBat.toString()}"
)

if (result == 0) { // integer comparison now
  echo 'My result: Success'
  currentBuild.result = 'SUCCESS'
}
else if (result == -1){ // integer comparison now
  echo 'My result: Failure -1'
  currentBuild.result = 'FAILURE'
}
else {
  echo 'My result: Failure unknown'
  currentBuild.result = 'FAILURE'
}
```

This will be easier and work as expected for you. Note the relevant [documentation for the bat method](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-durable-task-step/#-bat-windows-batch-script).

Comment: Hi Matt, 
Thanks for your answer. I have tried it but it seems to not work as expected.

´
sometext
-1

[Pipeline] echo

Myresult: Success

[Pipeline] }

[Pipeline] // script

[Pipeline] }

[Pipeline] // stage

[Pipeline] }

[Pipeline] // withEnv

[Pipeline] }

[Pipeline] // node

[Pipeline] End of Pipeline

Finished: SUCCESS
´
Expected was a failure with the echo "My result: Failure -1"

Sry I can't get the Format the way I want. SO just removes my cr lf....

So basically when I get an -1 for result, the if statement doesn't catch it.

Comment: the problem was in the Powershell script. I used return 1 instead of exit 1.

Answer (score 1):

Due to `returnStdout: true` your "some text" is actually part of what is returned, and obviously it is not "0", hence the else branch. You probably want to replace `returnStdout` with `returnStatus`.

Comment: I changed it to returnStatus.
When result the returnvalue of the is -1, the if statement doesnt catch -1. Something is still wrong.

Comment: I lost track, how does your script look now after the changes?